# Laravel Vue.js components are not working on server

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to Laravel Vue and I recently came to a project. at my localhost everything working fine, but when I pushed my project to the server via git, the Vue components not working. it says this error in the console...

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'  app.js:1

there is no npm install on the server so I run the command locally "npm run production" and pushed the app.js and all other js files via git to the server.. the server files are the same as localhost but Vue components not working on the server, but they are running on localhost..., I am stuck to the problem with 3 days, any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Just for clarity, the CSS file is rendering but the JS file not

In my console:

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type `text/html`: `/rider/auth/public/css/app.css`.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' app.js:1

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show how you are loading your scripts?

Comment: yes i run npm run production on localhost and pushed my code to server via git. everything working on localhost fine ,but on server this issue coming in console

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: No in your view how do you load the code?

Comment: I uploaded the picture , as you can see the details

Comment: I am a bit confused why your app.js file is containing html? Are you sure this was compiled correctly?

Comment: this is a laravel blade file , and I have included the link to app.js file .. I compiled the js with "npm run production" and then uploaded to server .. the localhost is working fine , but production server is showing this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231673/discussion-between-aless55-and-junior-developer).

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was in the .env file , and there was a variable "ASSET_URL = ./public" , this was not allowing the application to go to the correct path . Thanks @Aless55 for your great support